# How to display a dialog from a Library?

Tags: android, dialog, alert, aar

I'm writing a custom library, and I ran into a problem. I need to display a dialog to prompt a user to login one time. I can't seem to be able to display an AlertDialog from the Library. I get Unable to add window -- token is not for an application. I am getting the context of the application, by extending a custom library application class. This is the application class in the library:

```
public class MyCustomApplication extends Application {
private static MyCustomApplication instance;

/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public MyCustomApplication () {
    instance = this;
}

/**
 * Gets the application context.
 *
 * @return the application context
 */
public static Context getContext() {
    return instance;
}
```

And this is the code in the app that is using the library:

```
public class MyApplication extends MyCustomApplication {

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
}
```

This is the code in the library that attempts to display a dialog:

```
public static void displayTerminatePopup(String title, String message){
    int size = 14;

    AlertDialog.Builder aboutBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyCustomApplication.getContext());
    aboutBuilder
            .setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setCancelable(false);
            .setPositiveButton("Accept",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
    final AlertDialog aboutAlert = aboutBuilder.create();
    aboutAlert.show();
    TextView textView = (TextView)  aboutAlert.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    textView.setTextSize(size);
}
```

The 'MyCustomApplication.getContext() is where I'm 99% sure the hang up is. I also tried passing a Context directly to the library, and that didn't work, either. Any help on how to show a dialog to allow a user to login via a library would be much appreciated. I've been searching and searching and havn't been able to find anything.

Thanks!